# Typescript error when extending a forwardRef component e.g) ListItem.Placeholder = ListItemPlaceholder

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to put the `ListItemPlaceholder` under the `ListItem` component. The `ListItem` uses forward ref in it. But the typescript complains about this even though I already do this: `ListItem.Placeholder = ListItemPlaceholder` at the end of the file.

TS2322: Type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<Props & RefAttributes>' is not assignable to type 'ListItemComponent'.   Property 'Placeholder' is missing in type 'ForwardRefExoticComponent<Props & RefAttributes>' but required in type '{ Placeholder: FunctionComponent<{}>; }'.

Example:

```
type ListItemComponent = ForwardRefExoticComponent<Props> & {
  Placeholder: typeof ListItemPlaceholder;
};

export const ListItem: ListItemComponent = forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  Props
>((props, ref) => {
   //.....
   return <div ref={ref}/>
}))

const ListItemPlaceholder: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return <div/>
};

ListItem.Placeholder = ListItemPlaceholder
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a type-mismatch problem. And maybe the problem is with the placeholder type.
You can make these changes and try.

```
const ListItemPlaceholder: FunctionComponent = () => {
  return <div/>
};

type ListItemComponent = ForwardRefExoticComponent<Props> & {
  Placeholder: typeof ListItemPlaceholder;
};

export const ListItem: ListItemComponent = forwardRef<
  HTMLDivElement,
  Props
>((props, ref) => {
   //.....
   return <div ref={ref}/>
}));

ListItem.Placeholder = ListItemPlaceholder;
```

You should always declare a variable or type before it is used.

Comment: If it helped you then please don't forgot to accept answer correct!